# Failure expanding variable do_install: ShellSyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am trying to build the recipe tk_8.6.6.bb in the yocto project, but I keep on getting the following error.

> ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing
>   /home/mshehery/Release_7.3/sheheryar_containers/yocto/fido/meta/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/tcltk/tk_8.6.6.bb:
>   Failure expanding variable do_install: ShellSyntaxError: Unexpected
>   EOF

Here is the code in the recipe that refers to the do_install function

```
do_install_append() {

    ln -sf libtk${VER}.so ${D}${libdir}/libtk${VER}.so.0
    oe_libinstall -so libtk${VER} ${D}${libdir}
    ln -sf wish${VER} ${D}${bindir}/wish

    if [ "$libdir" != "/usr/lib" ]; then
        # Move files to correct library directory
        mv ${D}/usr/lib/tk${VER}/* ${D}/${libdir}/tk${VER}/
        # Remove unneeded/incorrect dir ('usr/lib/')
        rm -rf ${D}/usr/lib
    fi
}
```

Can anybody point out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the full `do_install()` function?  As your function is a `do_install_append()` it is appending to the main `do_install()` and the error you receive explicitly states:

> Failure expanding variable do_install: ShellSyntaxError: Unexpected
>   EOF